# Most customer that order most product together with productname and customername and amount they ordered

Tags: sql

Here is the table with the records insides

```
Customers      91
Employees      10
OrderDetails  518
Orders        196
Products       77
Shippers        3
Suppliers      29
```

and here is the sql query i thought but i am not sure if i am getting right result I need help

```
Select customername, productname, Sum(price * quantity) as price, max (quantity) as Qantity_ordered
From customers
Inner join orders
   On  customers.customerId = orders.customerid
Inner Join Orderdetails
    On orders.orderid = orderdetails.orderid
Inner Join Products
    On orderdetails.productid = products.productid
;
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Your question would also be clearer with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you will need the following statement:

```
Select customername, 
    productname, 
    max(Temp.price) as price,
    Temp.quantity as Qantity_ordered
FROM
(Select customerid, productid, Sum(price * quantity) as price, max (quantity) as Qantity_ordered
    From customers
    Inner join orders
    On  customers.customerId = orders.customerid
    Inner Join Orderdetails
    On orders.orderid = orderdetails.orderid
    Inner Join Products
    On orderdetails.productid = products.productid
    Group By customerid, productid) Temp
Inner Join customers 
On customerId = Temp.customerId
Inner join orders
On  Temp.customerId = orders.customerid
Inner Join Orderdetails
On orders.orderid = orderdetails.orderid
Inner Join Products p
On  p.productid = Temp.productid
where quantity = Temp.Qantity_ordered
Group By customername, 
   productname, 
   Temp.quantity
```